# Is it recommended to drop custom or secondary indexes before an upgrade?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

During the upgrade of cassandra either Apache or DSE , is it recommended to drop the existing Custom or secondary indexes .Can we go ahead with upgrade without dropping indexes. If we dont drop can we encounter with any issues. Please let me know.

Regards

Custom indexes are required to drop or can we go ahead without dropping during upgrade

Comment: What version are you referring to?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could find if there any is any special requirements for the versions that you're doing in the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrading/docs/upgrdAbout.html) as you haven't specified what is the source and target versions. Also, with DSE, if you're using advanced workloads, there are separate instructions for them to prepare for an upgrade. Once you have had a chance to update your questions with details, we may be able to get you more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general recommendation to drop indexes prior to upgrading Cassandra or DataStax Enterprise.

If you are running your own custom indexes then you need to know yourself what the requirements are since they're your custom implementation.

If you are using the DSE Search functionality in DataStax Enterprise, there are steps you will need to follow to prepare for an upgrade. The required steps depend on the DSE version. For details, see the relevant sections of [Upgrading DataStax Enterprise](https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrading/docs/datastax_enterprise/upgrdDSE.html). Cheers!